# Multitask: parse space-separated integers from a string

Tags: java, string, parsing, split, int

I have a problem with task.

My job is

- grab a `String` from a file (in source file are numbers in one line, divided by spaces)
- split that string by spaces
- then parse each `String` to an `int`
- and finally use bubbleSort on them.

I'm stucked on parsing, don't get any idea how to do it.

Code atm looks sth like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String numbers = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\README.txt")));
        String s[] = numbers.split(" ");
        for (String element : s)
        {
           System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use a scanner to read string numbers, then loop it for parseInt, but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you get any error trying parseInt? Please elaborate your problems :)

Answer (score 2):

The method you are looking for is [Integer#parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-)

When using **Java 8** you could make use of the [Stream API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) like follows:

```
final List<Integer> intList = new LinkedList<>();

try {
    Files.lines(Paths.get("path\\to\\yourFile.txt"))
        .map(line -> line.split(" "))
        .flatMap(Stream::of)
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .forEach(intList::add);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Without streams:

```
final List<Integer> intList = new LinkedList<>();

try {
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path\\to\\yourFile.txt"))) {
        for (String numberLiteral : line.split(" ")) {
            intList.add(Integer.parseInt(numberLiteral));
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  public class Main
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
      {
          String numbers = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\README.txt")));
          String s[] = numbers.split(" ");
          for (String element : s)
          {
             int number = Integer.valueOf(element)  // transform String to int 
             System.out.println(number);
          }
      }
  }
```

i think one idea would be to transform the whole `String-Array` to an `int-array` or `List of Integers`

this can be done, with this method (nearly the same like above):

```
  private List<Integer> transformToInteger(final String[] s) {
      final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for (String element : s)
      {
        final int number = Integer.valueOf(element);
        result.add(number);
      }
      return result;
    }
```

and now you can perform your bubble sort on this result List.